# How can I use the GitHub API v3 to extract historical statistics about a repository - number of stargazers, issues, etc?

Tags: python, github, github-api

I want to gather and analyse statistics about open-source code repositories using GitHub's API (v3), for example the number of stargazers for a repository.

I would like to gather historical data about repositories also, e.g. number of stargazers this day last year.

The API docs (https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#list-stargazers) provide a way of extracting the time at which a user starred the repository, so I looked into simply counting the number of star events before a specific date, but for repositories with a lot of stargazers, e.g. twitter bootstrap - 130K, this doesn't work since the API limits the amount of results returned to < 50,000.

Is there a way to extract statistics about a repository for a specific date in the past using the API directly or through a library?